# Tracking podcast listening history in iOS or Android

Tags: android, ios, iphone

Is it possible to record/track which Podcast a user is listening to on iPhone or Android? Obviously the app would ask for explicit permission from the user before tracking this information. Does iOS or Android allow a third party app access to podcast or music history?

I checked Apple's developer resources and it looks like they allow apps to track users music history but doesn't say anything about Podcasts.

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-privacy-details/#data-type

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow @Is2525! In order to get good answers to your question I would recommend adding some research you've done and why it hasn't reached a conclusion, code samples you've tried and what the issues were etc. You might want to take a look here for some tips on how to ask a good question - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Music listening data in that table refers to a *type of data* that your app may record and you would need to consider in your privacy disclosure. It is not a list of data that is available from iOS. As a general rule an iOS app cannot access information from another app aside from specific information (such as contents, photos or location) and only with user permission. iOS does not provide access to music or podcast listening data.  The only way you could track podcast listening history would be if you wrote a podcast app and you tracked only the podcasts the user played in your app.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for your answer. I believe there are some music logs which third party apps can access with user's permission. I found this app called Play Tally [Play Tally](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/playtally-your-music-stats/id1513271356) They show your music stats. I wonder how they do it?

Comment: That app is essentially an alternative music player. If you read its description it states “PlayTally reports its own data.  Earlier playback history cannot be accessed to recreated”

Comment: There is a [history](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemusicapi/history) web services api and there is probably some similar api for Spotify but no on-device api for playback history across apps. Remember a user may use Apples podcast app or the Spotify app or overcast or ... to play podcasts.

Comment: That is fair enough. Spotify has an API that lets you download music history (again I am not sure about Podcast history). But lets say if I just want to track podcasts played on Apple Podcasts app, is it possible to do that?

Comment: I downloaded that app, it shows music history from the day you download it. It tracks all of my music played on Apple's music app. So that tells me there is some music history store in iOS